# how do I print an unsigned char as hex in c++ using ostream?

Tags: c++, formatting, cout, ostream, unsigned-char

I want to work with unsigned 8-bit variables in C++.  Either `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` do the trick as far as the arithmetic is concerned (which is expected, since AFAIK `uint8_t` is just an alias for `unsigned char`, or so the debugger presents it.

The problem is that if I print out the variables using ostream in C++ it treats it as char.  If I have:

```
unsigned char a = 0;
unsigned char b = 0xff;
cout << "a is " << hex << a <<"; b is " << hex << b << endl;
```

then the output is:

```
a is ^@; b is 377
```

instead of

```
a is 0; b is ff
```

I tried using `uint8_t`, but as I mentioned before, that's typedef'ed to `unsigned char`, so it does the same.  How can I print my variables correctly?

**Edit:** I do this in many places throughout my code.  Is there any way I can do this *without* casting to `int` each time I want to print?

Comment: I think MartinStettner's answer is rather confusing, I don't think it is worth to implement an extra struct and an extra stream operator. anon's solution is straight forward and works good enough for me.

Comment: mark: In C++, `std::cout` treats variables of type `char` and `unsigned char` as character types, and outputs them as characters. To output their integer values, it is necessary to cast them to `int` type.    


`std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << (int)(unsigned char)c;`  
// or    
`std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << (c & 0xff);`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I would suggest using the following technique:

```
struct HexCharStruct
{
  unsigned char c;
  HexCharStruct(unsigned char _c) : c(_c) { }
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const HexCharStruct& hs)
{
  return (o << std::hex << (int)hs.c);
}

inline HexCharStruct hex(unsigned char _c)
{
  return HexCharStruct(_c);
}

int main()
{
  char a = 131;
  std::cout << hex(a) << std::endl;
}
```

It's short to write, has the same efficiency as the original solution and it lets you choose to use the "original" character output. And it's type-safe (not using "evil" macros :-))

Comment: As long as we're eschewing macros: in order to be more fully C++, shouldn't you write `(int)hs.c` as `static_cast<int>(hs.c)`? :P

Comment: There is a slight bug in your code.
If you feed a negative character in the code the hex value becomes 4 bytes instead of 2.
Switching to `unsigned char` fixes the problem.

Comment: Another bug(?) is that the above `operator<<` changes the mode of the given stream to hexadecimal: `cout << hex(a) << 100` will give you a surprise. You should store the state of the stream before modifying it, and restore it later.

Comment: I'm truly amazed at how bad C++ is at converting `char` to hex.

Comment: @CraigRinger, to make the fun even more exquisite: `cout << hex << (int)'x' << ", " << (uint8_t)'x';` would still only give hex for the first one, and not the second, as `uint8_t` is not even a number, but just a char typedef.  And sure enough `... << (byte)'x'` wouldn't even compile, as there's no `<<` for `byte`. :) I't hilarious indeed.

Answer (score 62):

Use:

```
cout << "a is " << hex << (int) a <<"; b is " << hex << (int) b << endl;
```

And if you want padding with leading zeros then:

```
#include <iomanip>
...
cout << "a is " << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hex << (int) a ;
```

As we are using C-style casts, why not go the whole hog with terminal C++ badness and use a macro!

```
#define HEX( x )
   setw(2) << setfill('0') << hex << (int)( x )
```

you can then say

```
cout << "a is " << HEX( a );
```

**Edit:** Having said that, MartinStettner's solution is much nicer!

Comment: Can I convince you to eschew the evil C-style casts once and for all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527999/is-it-ok-to-use-c-style-cast-for-built-in-types/528009#528009

Comment: Not in this case - it's about the only place I think they are justified.

Comment: I would do it the same, except to avoid the cast I would use cout << hex << int(a);  It means the same thing as a cast, without the cast. :)

Answer (score 41):

You can read more about this at http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/09/tippet-printing-numeric-values-for-chars-and-uint8_t/ and http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/08/code-critique-stack-overflow-posters-cant-print-the-numeric-value-of-a-char/.  I am only posting this because it has become clear that the author of the above articles does not intend to.

The simplest and most correct technique to do print a char as hex is

```
unsigned char a = 0;
unsigned char b = 0xff;
auto flags = cout.flags(); //I only include resetting the ioflags because so
                           //many answers on this page call functions where
                           //flags are changed and leave no way to  
                           //return them to the state they were in before 
                           //the function call
cout << "a is " << hex << +a <<"; b is " << +b << endl;
cout.flags(flags);
```

The readers digest version of how this works is that the unary + operator forces a no op type conversion to an int with the correct signedness.  So, an unsigned char converts to unsigned int, a signed char converts to int, and a char converts to either unsigned int or int depending on whether char is signed or unsigned on your platform (it comes as a shock to many that char is special and not specified as either signed or unsigned).

The only negative of this technique is that it may not be obvious what is happening to a someone that is unfamiliar with it. However, I think that it is better to use the technique that is correct and teach others about it rather than doing something that is incorrect but more immediately clear.

Comment: Why is this not the top answer? It is short and effective.

Comment: This technique sign-extends types smaller than `unsigned int` / `int`, which means for negative signed chars (or int16_t for example), you'll get 8 nibbles of output, the first 6 of which are `F`.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland I noticed that issue even for unsigned char (when greater than 127), so I solved it with a bitmask: `(+c & 0xFF)`.

Comment: @To마SE, the unary `+` is unnecessary, the binary `&` already converts to an `int`.

Answer (score 35):

Well, this works for me:

```
std::cout << std::hex << (0xFF & a) << std::endl;
```

If you just cast `(int)` as suggested it might add 1s to the left of `a` if its most significant bit is 1. So making this binary AND operation guarantees the output will have the left bits filled by 0s and also converts it to unsigned int forcing cout to print it as hex.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is the simplest and cleanest method of the bunch.

Comment: I really like this answer too! I used this solution.

Comment: This works, but any suggestion on how I can prefix characters <= 9 to have a 0 prepended?

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev you can do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714515/how-can-i-pad-an-int-with-leading-zeros-when-using-cout-operator

Answer (score 26):

In C++20 you can use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) to do this:

```
std::cout << std::format("a is {:x}; b is {:x}\n", a, b);
```

Output:

```
a is 0; b is ff
```

If it is not available you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on. {fmt} also provides the `print` function that makes this even easier and more efficient ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MfP1rr)):

```
fmt::print("a is {:x}; b is {:x}\n", a, b);
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.

Comment: Best modern response. No need to muck about with `std::hex`, `std::uppercase`, and all that jazz when I can just do

`std::cout << std::format("0x{:02X} ", (unsigned char)ch);`

Answer (score 6):

Hm, it seems I re-invented the wheel yesterday... But hey, at least it's a generic wheel this time :) `char`s are printed with two hex digits, `short`s with 4 hex digits and so on.

```
template<typename T>
struct hex_t
{
    T x;
};

template<typename T>
hex_t<T> hex(T x)
{
    hex_t<T> h = {x};
    return h;
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, hex_t<T> h)
{
    char buffer[2 * sizeof(T)];
    for (auto i = sizeof buffer; i--; )
    {
        buffer[i] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[h.x & 15];
        h.x >>= 4;
    }
    os.write(buffer, sizeof buffer);
    return os;
}
```

Comment: I like it. Succinct. No redundant info required. I'd love a bool to indicate whether upper or lowercase is desired. Or honour the [`std::uppercase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/uppercase) and [`std::nouppercase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/nouppercase) manipulators (which manipulate the [`std::ios_base::flags::uppercase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags) iosflag)

Answer (score 5):

I think TrungTN and anon's answer is okay, but MartinStettner's way of implementing the hex() function is not really simple, and too dark, considering hex << (int)mychar is already a workaround.

here is my solution to make "<<" operator easier:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

string uchar2hex(unsigned char inchar)
{
  ostringstream oss (ostringstream::out);
  oss << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hex << (int)(inchar);
  return oss.str();
}

int main()
{
  unsigned char a = 131;
  std::cout << uchar2hex(a) << std::endl;
}
```

It's just not worthy implementing a stream operator :-)

Answer (score 5):

I think we are missing an explanation of how these type conversions work.

`char` is platform dependent `signed` or `unsigned`. In x86 `char` is equivalent to `signed char`.

When an integral type (`char`, `short`, `int`, `long`) is converted to a larger capacity type, the conversion is made by adding zeros to the left in case of `unsigned` types and by sign extension for `signed` ones. Sign extension consists in replicating the most significant (leftmost) bit of the original number to the left till we reach the bit size of the target type.

Hence if I am in a `signed char` by default system and I do this:

```
char a = 0xF0; // Equivalent to the binary: 11110000
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(a);
```

We would obtain `F...F0` since the leading `1` bit has been extended.

If we want to make sure that we only print `F0` in any system we would have to make an additional intermediate type cast to an `unsigned char` so that zeros are added instead and, since they are not significant for a integer with only 8-bits, not printed:

```
char a = 0xF0; // Equivalent to the binary: 11110000
std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(a));
```

This produces `F0`

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it like MartinStettner but add an extra parameter for number of digits:

```
inline HexStruct hex(long n, int w=2)
{
  return HexStruct(n, w);
}
// Rest of implementation is left as an exercise for the reader
```

So you have two digits by default but can set four, eight, or whatever if you want to.

eg.

```
int main()
{
  short a = 3142;
  std:cout << hex(a,4) << std::endl;
}
```

It may seem like overkill but as Bjarne said: "libraries should be easy to use, not easy to write".

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

```
std::cout << setbase(16) << 32;
```

Taken from:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/iomanip.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```
unsigned char a = 0;
unsigned char b = 0xff;
cout << hex << "a is " << int(a) << "; b is " << int(b) << endl;
cout << hex
     <<   "a is " << setfill('0') << setw(2) << int(a)
     << "; b is " << setfill('0') << setw(2) << int(b)
     << endl;
cout << hex << uppercase
     <<   "a is " << setfill('0') << setw(2) << int(a)
     << "; b is " << setfill('0') << setw(2) << int(b)
     << endl;
```

Output:

**`a is 0; b is ff`**

**`a is 00; b is ff`**

**`a is 00; b is FF`**

Comment: While this does solve the problem, one of my requirements was not to have to cast to `int` whenever I want to do this, since this appears too many times in the code.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following on win32/linux(32/64 bit):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename T>
std::string HexToString(T uval)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "0x" << std::setw(sizeof(uval) * 2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << +uval;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but its also a top Google result in searching for  a solution to a very similar problem I have, which is the desire to implement arbitrary integer to hex string conversions within a template class.  My end goal was actually a `Gtk::Entry` subclass template that would allow editing various integer widths in hex, but that's beside the point.

This combines the unary `operator+` trick with `std::make_unsigned` from `<type_traits>` to prevent the problem of sign-extending negative `int8_t` or `signed char` values that occurs in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28355222/942746)

Anyway, I believe this is more succinct than any other generic solution. It should work for *any* signed or unsigned integer types, and throws a compile-time error if you attempt to instantiate the function with any non-integer types.

```
template < 
  typename T,
  typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type
>
std::string toHexString(const T v)
{ 
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss << std::hex << +((typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type)v);
  return oss.str();
}
```

Some example usage:

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  int16_t val;
  // Prints 'ff' instead of "ffffffff". Unlike the other answer using the '+'
  // operator to extend sizeof(char) int types to int/unsigned int
  std::cout << toHexString(int8_t(-1)) << std::endl;

  // Works with any integer type
  std::cout << toHexString(int16_t(0xCAFE)) << std::endl;

  // You can use setw and setfill with strings too -OR- 
  // the toHexString could easily have parameters added to do that.
  std::cout << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << 
    toHexString(int(100)) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Update:** Alternatively, if you don't like the idea of the `ostringstream` being used, you can combine the templating and unary operator trick with the accepted answer's struct-based solution for the following.  Note that here, I modified the template by removing the check for integer types.  The `make_unsigned` usage might be enough for compile time type safety guarantees.

```
template <typename T>
struct HexValue 
{
  T value;
  HexValue(T _v) : value(_v) { }
};

template <typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const HexValue<T>& hs)
{
  return o << std::hex << +((typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type) hs.value);
}

template <typename T>
const HexValue<T> toHex(const T val)
{
  return HexValue<T>(val);
}

// Usage:
std::cout << toHex(int8_t(-1)) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to post my re-re-inventing version based on @FredOverflow's. I made the following modifications.

fix:

- Rhs of `operator<<` should be of `const` reference type. In @FredOverflow's code, `h.x >>= 4` changes output `h`, which is surprisingly not compatible with standard library, and type `T` is requared to be copy-constructable.
- Assume only `CHAR_BITS` is a multiple of 4. @FredOverflow's code assumes `char` is 8-bits, which is not always true, in some implementations on DSPs, particularly, it is not uncommon that `char` is 16-bits, 24-bits, 32-bits, etc.

improve:

- Support all other standard library manipulators available for integral types, e.g. `std::uppercase`. Because format output is used in `_print_byte`, standard library manipulators are still available.
- Add `hex_sep` to print separate bytes (note that in C/C++ a 'byte' is by definition a storage unit with the size of `char`). Add a template parameter `Sep` and instantiate `_Hex<T, false>` and `_Hex<T, true>` in `hex` and `hex_sep` respectively.
- Avoid binary code bloat. Function `_print_byte` is extracted out of `operator<<`, with a *function parameter* `size`, to avoid instantiation for different `Size`.

More on binary code bloat:

As mentioned in improvement 3, no matter how extensively `hex` and `hex_sep` is used, only two copies of (nearly) duplicated function will exits in binary code: `_print_byte<true>` and `_print_byte<false>`. And you might realized that this duplication can also be eliminated using exactly the same approach: add a function parameter `sep`. Yes, but if doing so, a runtime `if(sep)` is needed. I want a common library utility which may be used extensively in the program, thus I compromised on the duplication rather than runtime overhead. I achieved this by using compile-time `if`: C++11 `std::conditional`, the overhead of function call can hopefully be optimized away by `inline`.

hex_print.h:

```
namespace Hex
{
typedef unsigned char Byte;

template <typename T, bool Sep> struct _Hex
{
    _Hex(const T& t) : val(t)
    {}
    const T& val;
};

template <typename T, bool Sep>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const _Hex<T, Sep>& h);
}

template <typename T>  Hex::_Hex<T, false> hex(const T& x)
{ return Hex::_Hex<T, false>(x); }

template <typename T>  Hex::_Hex<T, true> hex_sep(const T& x)
{ return Hex::_Hex<T, true>(x); }

#include "misc.tcc"
```

hex_print.tcc:

```
namespace Hex
{

struct Put_space {
    static inline void run(std::ostream& os) { os << ' '; }
};
struct No_op {
    static inline void run(std::ostream& os) {}
};

#if (CHAR_BIT & 3) // can use C++11 static_assert, but no real advantage here
#error "hex print utility need CHAR_BIT to be a multiple of 4"
#endif
static const size_t width = CHAR_BIT >> 2;

template <bool Sep>
std::ostream& _print_byte(std::ostream& os, const void* ptr, const size_t size)
{
    using namespace std;

    auto pbyte = reinterpret_cast<const Byte*>(ptr);

    os << hex << setfill('0');
    for (int i = size; --i >= 0; )
    {
        os << setw(width) << static_cast<short>(pbyte[i]);
        conditional<Sep, Put_space, No_op>::type::run(os);
    }
    return os << setfill(' ') << dec;
}

template <typename T, bool Sep>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const _Hex<T, Sep>& h)
{
    return _print_byte<Sep>(os, &h.val, sizeof(T));
}

}
```

test:

```
struct { int x; } output = {0xdeadbeef};
cout << hex_sep(output) << std::uppercase << hex(output) << endl;
```

output:

`de ad be ef DEADBEEF`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using prefill and signed chars, be careful not to append unwanted 'F's

`char out_character = 0xBE;
 cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << unsigned short(out_character);`

prints: ffbe

using int instead of short results in ffffffbe

To prevent the unwanted f's you can easily mask them out.

`char out_character = 0xBE;
 cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << unsigned short(out_character) & 0xFF;`

Answer (score -2):

This will also work:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, unsigned char c)
{
    return o<<(int)c;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char a = 06;
    unsigned char b = 0xff;
    std::cout << "a is " << std::hex << a <<"; b is " << std::hex << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But then he has to use casts if he actually wants them output as chars, which seems a little unnatural!

Answer (score -2):

I have used in this way.

```
    char strInput[] = "yourchardata";
char chHex[2] = "";

int nLength = strlen(strInput);
char* chResut = new char[(nLength*2) + 1];
memset(chResut, 0, (nLength*2) + 1);



for (int i = 0; i < nLength; i++)
{
    sprintf(chHex, "%02X", strInput[i]& 0x00FF);    
    memcpy(&(chResut[i*2]), chHex, 2);
}

printf("\n%s",chResut);
delete chResut;
chResut = NULL;
```

Comment: This is a question about C++ and std::ostream not about C and printf. :)