# char to hex stream output in C++ using GCC 4.2.1

Tags: c++, formatting, char, hex, iostream

I have looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673240/how-do-i-print-an-unsigned-char-as-hex-in-c-using-ostream) and can't get it to work for my situation. Please don't mark this as a duplicate as I can't get any of those answers to satisfy my situation.

I am `malloc`ing some memory and copying data into that memory. I want to be able to print out the values of each of the bytes in hex in the format `0xFF` where a byte equals `255`.

I have cast my `void*` pointer to the memory as `char*` and am iterating the block of memory, but when I try and print out the values I get very wide output instead of two digits I get the full width of the `unsigned int`.

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &os, const Binary &obj)
{
    char* aschar = (char*) obj.buffer;
    for (long i = 0; i < obj.size; i++) 
    {
        if (isprint(aschar[i])) 
        {
            os << aschar[i];
        }
        else 
        {
            os << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned int> (aschar[i]);
        }
    }
    return os;
}
```

I am `memset`ing all the bytes to `128` in my test case. And all what I get back is `ffffff80` when I am expecting `80`. I am sure it has something to do with the casting and what not but I can't figure out how to express this the way I want it to.

I have also tried using `sprintf` and I can't get it to behave the way I want it to either. I am using Xcode 3.2.5 64 bit with GCC 4.2.1 if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unsigned char *aschar` instead of (signed) `char *aschar`.