# Print an OpenCL cl_uchar in hex format using cout in C++?

Tags: c++, hex, opencl, cout

I'm trying to verify my pointers are in place and I'd like to print the value of a `cl_uchar` (unsigned char OpenCL type) in hex format.  I tried:

`cout << "Data matrix 0,3 = " << clMatrixPerm->data_matrix->elements[4] << endl;`

and

`cout << "Data matrix 0,3 = " << hex << clMatrixPerm->data_matrix->elements[4] << endl;`

where `clMatrixPerm->data_matrix->elements[4]` is the data in the array to be printed. In both cases there was no output after `Data matrix 0,3 =`.  I was able to use a workaround with printf so I know the data is being assigned correctly, but I'd like to print it using cout if possible.

Comment: Does casting it to an int type work?

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to be able to see it in hex.  I tried casting it to unsigned char also, but no success.

Comment: The top answer [given here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673240/how-do-i-print-an-unsigned-char-as-hex-in-c-using-ostream) works on my platform for `cl_uchar`.

Comment: Thanks James, that worked.  I decided to use the solution of casting the data to int and then using the hex cout operator.  I think that's what anthony-arnold was getting at but I didn't understand until I looked at your link.

Comment: @James You might want to add that as an answer here so it can be accepted and is easy to find for future reference :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple

```
cout << "Data matrix 0,3 = " << hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(clMatrixPerm->data_matrix->elements[4]) << endl;
```