# Gcc: force compiler to use unsigned char by default

Tags: c++, gcc, char, unsigned

Since the nature of a `char` in C++ is compiler-dependent when the `unsigned` qualifier is not present, is there an argument I could pass on to GCC which would **force** all `char`s to be compiled as `unsigned`?

Comment: I found this out in ten seconds by Googling `gcc force unsigned char` then reading the GCC documentation that comes up. What prevented you from performing this research?

Comment: @LRO, because you are clearly much quicker than trawling through google... ;)

Comment: It's probably better to use `unsigned char` rather than plain `char`. Your program will likely be linked with code that was compiled without `-funsigned-char`. If you depend on unsigned bytes, it's safer to express that in the code rather than in a compiler option.

Comment: @Keith -- that is the craziest comment I've read here.  A plain text ascii file doesn't know if the bytes are signed or unsigned, let alone memory.  Some platforms have char as unsigned by default.  The char data type specification was written to not be very particular about the signedness to begin with.

Comment: @B.Nadolson: You must not have read many comments if you think mine is the craziest. The question wasn't about ASCII text files, it was about the type `char`. The type `char` *is* very particular about its signedness. On some implementations it's particularly signed; on others it's particularly unsigned. If the signedness matters, you should use `signed char` or `unsigned char`; that's why they exist.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The flag you are looking for is `-funsigned-char`.

From [the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html):

> **`-funsigned-char`**
>
> Let the type `char` be unsigned, like `unsigned char`.
>
> Each kind of machine has a default for what `char` should be. It is either like `unsigned char` by default or like `signed char` by default.
>
> Ideally, a portable program should always use `signed char` or `unsigned char` when it depends on the signedness of an object. But many programs have been written to use plain `char` and expect it to be signed, or expect it to be unsigned, depending on the machines they were written for. This option, and its inverse, let you make such a program work with the opposite default.
>
> The type `char` is always a distinct type from each of `signed char` or `unsigned char`, even though its behavior is always just like one of those two.
>
> ---
>
> **`-fsigned-char`**
>
> Let the type `char` be signed, like `signed char`.
>
> Note that this is equivalent to `-fno-unsigned-char`, which is the negative form of `-funsigned-char`. Likewise, the option `-fno-signed-char` is equivalent to `-funsigned-char`.

This *only* impacts `char`; [types like `wchar_t` are unaffected](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44af632c1b9bf7b2).

Comment: Can you confirm this flag has no impact on the signedness of `wchar_t`?

Comment: @Antonio: No idea, sorry.

Comment: @Antonio: [Yes](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44af632c1b9bf7b2).

Answer (score 8):

As the other answers say, gcc's `-funsigned-char` option forces plain `char` to be unsigned.

But that may not be the best solution to your problem. You want unsigned characters, but by using a compiler-specific option you're encoding that information in the build command (the Makefile, build script, or just the command you type to compile your code). If the semantics of your program depend on having unsigned characters, it's better to record that information in your source code. It's clearer, and it's reduces the chance that someone will build your program incorrectly.

If you want unsigned characters, using `unsigned char`. If you want signed characters, use `signed char`. If you just want characters, and you're sure your program's behavior doesn't depend on whether they're signed or unsigned (say, if all stored values are in the range 0..127), use `char`.

Comment: Keith I have a question; I would normally agree with the last paragraph of your answer... except...  Many POSIX functions have documented interface that uses `char`, for example the ones that read files (with characters in them).  OK, now suppose I want to use them but I want to process bit representations of read characters, and only bit representation of `unsigned char` is guaranteed. So in that case, it would seem it would be proper to use `-funsigned-char` .  Do you disagree?

Comment: @MarkGaleck Yes, I disagree, though I can see your point. Normally lines of text are made up of `char` values, and if you want to read `unsigned char` values from a file it's rare for the file to be made up of lines (typically it would be a binary file). But if you really need to do that, you can cast a `char*` pointer that points to a line of text and cast it to `unsigned char*`. Remember that `-funsigned-char` doesn't cause the runtime library to treat plain `char` as unsigned; it only affects the code you compile with that option.

Comment: ah yes, I see, thank you, yes, I get "records" from files, that are not lines as such, but are `char *` pointers and I know how long after that the record is, yes I will cast them to `unsigned char*`

Comment: @MarkGaleck How are you getting these "records"? Would `fread` make more sense?

Comment: thank you!  I did not know about `fread` :) but well, my records are not of the fixed size, I just know what size to expect at any particular moment, but the sizes vary

Comment: @MarkGaleck Well, if you know how big the next record is, you can pass that size as a parameter to `fread`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8589688/827263

Comment: well yes, but the point of `fread` really is so that I can ready many records at once.

Comment: @MarkGaleck The point of `fread` is to read however many records you want to read. There's nothing wrong with reading one record at a time. What are you using now?

Comment: I see, sorry, ... I got the gist of `fread` wrong, it is like `read` except for `FILE *`.  Well OK, I generally work with file descriptors.  Anyway, after talking to you, I went and checked carefully, and found that I can just use `mmap` all the time.  So that solves the problem, I don't really need `funsigned-char`.  But it was good to learn stuff from you.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Not enough reputation to comment @Keith's answer.

The main reason I see to use `-funsigned-char` or `-fsigned-char` is when you want the following code

```
  printf("%d\n",'\x80');
```

to display either `-128` or `128`.

The comment about not relying on specific compilation settings is valid but here it is a bit simplifying reality. The main problem is that C leaves some part of the language to the implementation for efficiency reason, and usually you want to tune that implementation to suit best your application. In my opinion a professional developer should always go through *all* compiler flags and select the best for his needs. If you rely on some specific settings, your *unit tests* will of course cover that case, or assert it. If you port an application, you will look into the compilation settings of the original port.

Comment: What does "TMO" stand for?

Comment: I see. I'm not familiar with that construction. Doesn't seem grammatical to me, either. What does it mean?

Comment: After some googling, doing s/to/in/ might be clearer for you. Turns out I was using this for years but is incorrect indeed. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I had to check to confirm that that would even work, because character constants are of type `int`, but yes, `-funsigned-char` or `-fsigned-char` does affect the value of `'\x80'`. But if I cared, I'd just cast the constant to `signed char` or `unsigned char` rather than using a compiler option. Remember that those options apply only to code compiled with the options; library code will still use the implementation's choice of signedness for plain `char`. The options are there to cater to existing code that was written with unwarranted assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-funsigned-char` for that, or `-fsigned-char` for signed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option: `-funsigned-char`.

[source](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html)