# How can I concatenate an uint64_t to unsigned char* in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to concatenate a `uint64_t` to `unsigned char*`. I can not use `sprintf()`, `strcpy()`, and `strcat()` because they only accept `char*` as argument.

```
#include <cstdint>

// I want to concatenate these two:

unsigned char data[8] = "tJQVfvcj";
uint64_t num = 1732462110473334785;
```

The output should be equivalent to:

```
unsigned char concat[28] = "tJQVfvcj1732462110473334785";
```

The efficiency is also important, although it is the second priority. I highly appreciate any suggestions.

**Edit**: I used sprintf() like this:

```
  unsigned char data[9] = "tJQVfvcj";
  uint64_t num = 1732462110473334785;

  unsigned char concat[28];
  sprintf(concat, "%s%" PRId64 "", data, num);
```

However, it leads to this error:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: C or C++? Those are different languages.

Comment: Concatenate "with". There is also `std::to_string()`

Comment: Use std::format

Comment: `sprintf()` takes a format string, wherein you can specify formats for converting numbers.  In C++, `std::ostringstream` is yet another option.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen You are right. I am using C++ but I am flexible in changing to C. Do you know any solution for C++?

Comment: Is the question so trivial that deserves so many negative feedbacks? I tried various ways before post the question.

Comment: @ggorlen I tried ```sprintf(concat, "%s%" PRId64 "", data, num)``` and it leads to this error:  invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]. I updated the question.

Comment: The error message is very clear, use `char concat[28]` instead of `unsigned char[]`

Comment: @phuclv using ```char``` fixes the problem, but I need ```unsigned char``` later as an input to another function.

Comment: then change the other function to receive `char*` instead of `unsigned char*`. In the worst case just cast to the desired type

Comment: Unless you can guarantee that the data is always less than 10 characters, declaring a buffer of length of only 28 will lead to a buffer overrun.

Comment: @phuclv Unfortunately I can not change the other functions. It is in a library that I am using. So the question is how can I convert ```char*``` to ```unsigned char*``` safely?

Comment: @Ali -- Consider the reason why the type is `char *`.  A `char` can either be signed or unsigned, depending on the platform, compiler settings, etc.  Maybe if you changed your compiler settings to treat `char` as unsigned, then that may address the issue.

Comment: This may be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518527/gcc-force-compiler-to-use-unsigned-char-by-default)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I used the ```-funsigned-char``` flag. However, I still get the error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘const unsigned char*’. So I have to do another conversion. This is not efficient.

Comment: Why not simply do `static_cast<char *>(concat)`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are 3 distinct types so a function receiving `unsigned char` can't accept `char` even if char is unsigned. A cast is the only solution in this case