# Why does a char casted to an int not equal the original char?

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

Why does a casted `char c` stored in an `int` not be the same as the original `char`?

I have looked all over for an explanation and I can't seem to be able to store a `char` in an `int` and be able to compare it to another `int`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    char c = 255;
    int x = (int)c;
    cout << (x == 255) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs `0`. Why?

Comment: What do you get as the result of `(c < 0)`? Or if you `#include <limits>`, what do you get for `std::numeric_limits<char>::max()`?

Comment: Either `x == c` or `x == (char)255` will evaluate to true, due to the default integer promotions. But `x == 255` translates to `-1 == 255` on machines where the `char` is signed.

Comment: `cout << (c < 0) << endl;` outputs `1`. This doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: I understand that `x == c` and `x == (char)255` will equal true, but I am wondering why after casting the `c` to an `int` and comparing it to another `int` like `255` will return false.

Comment: Because `11111111 != 11111111111111111111111111111111` `char` is (signed), when cast to `int` the value is **sign-extended** to 32 bits.

Comment: @DylanMeiners Because `c = 255` is equivalent to `c = -1` when the `char` is signed.

Comment: @dxiv Usually. Conversions to a signed integer type from a value outside its range have implementation-defined behavior. Most implementations define it to wrap modulus `(1<<nbits)` just like is required for unsigned integer types.

Comment: @aschepler That's a good point to keep in mind, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast isn't the problem here. Trying to assign 255 into a char, which is an **8 bit signed** type, is. This most likely results in all bits being set, and is interpreted as -1, but you shouldn't be doing it in the first place. Try with 127 or lower, and it will print 1.

Comment: Note that it is implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned.

Comment: @Eugene, true in theory. Show me a single actual compiler where it isn't the case, though.I am ready to bet any amount on it being 8 bit signed value here, and also ready to bet rather high amount on 255 just being loaded into the bits and becoming -1.

Comment: Yes, that was the case. Switching the type to an `unsigned char` was the fix.

Comment: @BorisLipschitz You can force a compiler to use unsigned char by default with a command line flag: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20518559/459565.

Comment: Okay, one actual compiler where `char` is unsigned is gcc. (If the target architecture is ARM, for one case.)

Comment: Really? Gcc (arm target) has unsigned char by default?! I mean without forcing it with command line switch.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/ArchitectureSpecificsMemo#Summary

Comment: @BorisLipschitz -- "I've never seen that happen" is not sound engineering.