# cout not printing unsigned char

Tags: c++, printf, cout, unsigned-char

I am working on below code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

main() {
    unsigned char a;
    a=1;
    printf("%d", a);
    cout<<a;
}
```

It is printing 1 and some garbage.

Why `cout` is behaving so?

Comment: An `unsigned char` is not an `int`. Why are you telling `printf` it is?

Comment: What would you expect from sending a binary 1 to stout?

Comment: @chris `unsigned char` will be promoted to `unsigned` in a printf call, so the code is acceptable.

Comment: @john, Ah, silly me. I thought there was one for unsigned char because of the char one, but that just ends up making no sense really. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: the 32 first character codes are control codes and are non-printable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I print an unsigned char as hex in c++ using ostream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673240/how-do-i-print-an-unsigned-char-as-hex-in-c-using-ostream)

Comment: seems to work now. now its just std::cout printing garbage if it gets a  uint8_t.`std::cout << (uint8_t)3 << std::endl` prints a heart, even though clearly the proper representation for a byte with value 3 is not a heart, unless its a signed byte, then it would be reasonable.

Answer (score 42):

`cout << a` is printing a value which appears to be garbage to you. It is not garbage actually. It is just a *non-printable* ASCII character which is getting printed anyway. Note that ASCII character corresponding to `1` is non-printable.  You can check whether `a` is printable or not using, [`std::isprint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint) as:

```
std::cout << std::isprint(a) << std::endl;
```

It will print `0` (read: `false`) indicating the character is non-printable

--

Anyway, if you want your `cout` to print `1` also, then cast `a` to this:

```
cout << static_cast<unsigned>(a) << std::endl;
```

Comment: How about printing signed char in C++ using cout? What is expected and how it is defined? For eg: signed char a=-50; cout<<a;

Comment: This works but I'm wondering why? Shouldn't it be `unsigned int` rather than just `unsigned`? Because the `unsigned` keyword can be used with either `int` or `float` or any other in-built data types, right?

Comment: @Milan: `unsigned` is translated by compiler to be `unsigned int`.

Comment: I prefer the unary plus operator over an explicit cast: `std::cout << +a << '\n';`

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024566/c-printing-unsigned-char-values?noredirect=1#comment83018436_48024566) that I've long forgotten about. The resolution to this problem with `iostream's` `cout` can be done like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

main() {
    unsigned char a;
    a=1;
    printf("%d", a);
    std::cout<< +a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

instead of casting it back to another type if you want `cout` to print the `unsigned char` value as opposed to the `ascii` character. You need to `promote` it.

If you noticed all I did was add a `+` before the `unsigned char`. This is unary addition that will promote the `unsigned char` to give you the actual number representation.

User Baum mit Augen is responsible for reminding me of this solution.

Comment: That was sharpy :thumbup:

Answer (score 5):

You need to typecast `a` as integer as `cout<< (int)(a);`. With this you will observe `1` on the output. With `cout << a;`, the print will be `SOH (Start of Heading)` corresponding to ascii value of `1` which can't be printed and hence, some special character is observed.

**EDIT**:

To be more accurate, the `cout` statement should be `cout << static_cast<unsigned>(a)` as Nawaz has mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The C compiler has its own way of defining the type of the printed output, because you can specify the type of the output.

Ex:

```
uint8_t c = 100;
printf("%d",c);
```

so you can also print `c` as an int by `%d`, or char `%c`, string `%s` or a hex value `%x`.

Where C++ has its own way too, the `cout` prints the 8-bit values as a `char` by default. So, you have to use specifiers with the output argument.

You can either use:

1. a `+` before the name of the output argument

   ```
   uint8_t data_byte = 100;
   cout << "val: " << +data_byte << endl;
   ```
2. use a function cast `unsigned(var)`; like,

   ```
    uint8_t data_byte = 100;
    cout << "val: " << unsigned(data_byte) << endl;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A `char` will have a numerical value associated with it. The character represented by `1` is the `SOH` or `Start of header` character which is usually not printed (similar to printing the `NUL` character `\0`).

You can have a look at an [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/) to see which character will be printed, but an example with a value such as 65 might help. Where 65 is the `A` characater.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>


int main() {
    // initialise with an integer
    char a = 65;

    // print the integer representation
    printf("%d\n", a);

    // print as a character
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    // initialise with a character 
    char b = 'B';

    // print the integer representation
    printf("%d\n", b);
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(b) << std::endl;
    
    // print as a character
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
65
A
66
66
B
```

Answer (score -3):

printf("%u",a);
its so simple try it

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit more?

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.
In particular, please explain why you think that `%u` is better than `%hhu` for an `unsigned char` argument.

Comment: And this does nothing at all to address the question (why does `cout::operator<<(unsigned char)` interpret its argument as a character rather than as an arithmetic value?)