# c++ printing unsigned char values

Tags: c++, iostream

Consider the following:

```
int main() {
    unsigned char val(-1); 
    printf( "val = %u\n", val );
    return 0;
}
```

Ouptut:

```
val = 255
```

However when I try to use `iostream`

```
int main() {
    unsigned char val(-1);
    std::cout << "val = " << val << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
val =
```

Yet in the debugger when I check `val` it has the value `255` with the `y` with double dots above the `y`.

How can I get `iostream` to print out the same as `printf()` with the value of `255`

Comment: `std::cout << "val = " << +val << std::endl;` I'll look for a dupe.

Comment: Okay sure; no problem.

Comment: I'd argue a cast to `unsigned` is a bit clearer.

Comment: Wow; that did it; something so simple but forget the reason...

Comment: @DeiDei Agreed, but how else am I supposed to show off I know integer promotion rules? ;)

Comment: @BaummitAugen Good point.

Comment: @DeiDei for my purposes the promotion is better than a cast... I'm using it in a class template that takes any integral type `T` and in the `operator<<()` I'm printing out based on the `unsigned version` of `T`.