# why i am getting output blank?

Tags: c++, pointers

why I am getting output blank? pointers are able to modify but can't read.why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a = 0;
    char *x1,*x2,*x3,*x4;
    x1 = (char *)&a;
    x2 = x1;x2++;
    x3 = x2;x3++;
    x4 = x3;x4++;
    *x1=1;
    *x2=1;
    *x3=1;
    *x4=1;

    cout <<"@" << *x1 << " " << *x2 << " " << *x3 << " " << *x4 << "@"<<endl ;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

```
[Desktop] g++ test_pointer.cpp
[Desktop] ./a.out
@   @
16843009
```

I want to read the value of integer by using pointers type of char.
so i can read byte by byte.

Comment: you have undefined behaviour. you cannot point somewhere,  increment and then hope to get something meaningful. Pointer arithmetics is only well defined inside arrays

Comment: what  output do you want to generate? I am sure if you clarify that, there can be a solution that is valid (i even doubt you need pointers)

Comment: I disagree with the above comments about undefined behaviour and unallocated memory: the memory for `int a` is both allocated and initialized, and that memory is accessed via the `char *` pointers which is permitted as long as `int` is at least 4 `char`s wide. The value `16843009` is also correct (`0x01010101`). I think the unexpected output is simply that the individual bytes are printed as characters (as opposed to their integer values) and `0x01` is a control character.

Answer (score 6):

You're streaming `char`s. These get automatically ASCII-ised for you by IOStreams*, so [you're seeing (or rather, not seeing) *unprintable characters*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15585267/560648) (in fact, all 0x01 bytes).

You can cast to `int` to see the numerical value, and perhaps add `std::hex` for a conventional view.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;

    // Alias the first four bytes of `a` using `char*`
    char* x1 = (char*)&a;
    char* x2 = x1 + 1;
    char* x3 = x1 + 2;
    char* x4 = x1 + 3;

    *x1 = 1;
    *x2 = 1;
    *x3 = 1;
    *x4 = 1;

    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    std::cout << '@' << std::setw(2) << "0x" << (int)*x1
              << ' ' << std::setw(2) << "0x" << (int)*x2
              << ' ' << std::setw(2) << "0x" << (int)*x3
              << ' ' << std::setw(2) << "0x" << (int)*x4
              << '@' << '\n';
    std::cout << "0x" << a << '\n';
}

// Output:
//   @0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01@
//   0x1010101
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e5937dbcb49aa04))

Those saying that your program has undefined are incorrect (assuming your `int` has at least four bytes in it); aliasing objects via `char*` is specifically permitted.

The `16843009` output is correct; that's equal to `0x01010101` which you'd again see if you put your stream into hex mode.

---

N.B. Some people will recommend `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a)` and `static_cast<int>(*x1)`, instead of C-style casts, though personally I find them ugly and unnecessary in this particular case. For the output you can at least write `+*x1` to get a "free" promotion to `int` (via the unary `+` operator), but that's not terribly self-documenting.

---

<sub>* Technically it's something like the opposite; IOStreams *usually* automatically converts your numbers and booleans and things into the right ASCII characters to appear correct on screen. For `char` it skips that step, assuming that you're already providing the ASCII value you want.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an `int` is at least 4 bytes long on your system, the program manipulates the 4 bytes of `int a`.

The result `16843009` is the decimal value of `0x01010101`, so this is as you might expect.

You don't see anything in the first line of output because you write 4 characters of a binary value `1` (or `0x01`) which are invisible characters (ASCII SOH).

When you modify your program like this

```
*x1='1';
*x2='3';
*x3='5';
*x4='7';
```

you will see output with the expected characters

```
@1 3 5 7@
926233393
```

The value `926233393` is the decimal representation of `0x37353331` where `0x37` is the ASCII value of the character `'7'` etc.

(These results are valid for a little-endian architecture.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your declarations of the `x`'s

```
char *x1,*x2,*x3,*x4;
```

these are pointers to `chars` (characters).

In your stream output they are interpreted as printable characters.
A short look into the [ascii-Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) let you see that the lower numbers are not printeable.

Since your `int a` is zero also the `x`'s that point to the individual bytes are zero.

One possibility to get readeable output would be to cast the characters to `int`, so that the stream would print the numerical representation instead the ascii character:

```
cout <<"@" << int(*x1) << " " << int(*x2) << " " << int(*x3) << " " << int(*x4) << "@"<<endl ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use unary + for converting character type (printed as symbol) into integer type (printed as number):

```
cout <<"@" << +*x1 << " " << +*x2 << " " << +*x3 << " " << +*x4 << "@"<<endl ;
```

See [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, this is the solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a = 0;
    char *x1,*x2,*x3,*x4;
    x1 = (char*)&a;
    x2 = x1;x2++;
    x3 = x2;x3++;
    x4 = x3;x4++;
    *x1=1;
    *x2=1;
    *x3=1;
    *x4=1;
    cout <<"@" << (int)*x1 << " " << (int)*x2 << " " << (int)*x3 << " " << (int)*x4 << "@"<<endl ;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: Great, then you should mark the answer that helped you so that people will know that it is answered.

Comment: You should always _explain_ your proposed solution and how it resolves the stated problem. Don't just dump code. Also don't beg for answer accepts; it's only been 20 minutes since the question was posted.

Comment: and please don't use C-style casts and `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: TBH I'm fine with C-style casts for things like this cos `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a)` is ugly AF but yeah

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *cos `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a)` is ugly* – When casting the pointer it makes no difference but I meant the casts in the calls to `operator<<()` where a `static_cast<>()` would suffice.

Comment: @Swordfish Perhaps. I added a little thing to my answer about this a few mins ago

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You misunderstood my intention, I didn't mean that he should mark my own answer as accepted. I meant that he should mark the answer that helped him.
Also, I found this question while using the c filter in stack overflow, that's why I used C-style casts

Comment: The question (and your answer) are clearly C++, despite the bum tag ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm such a noob that I didn't even know, I just threw the code in my online IDE, added casts, and it worked.