# Convert a hexadecimal char value to its string literal to use on sstream

Tags: c++

I need to print the exact hex value of a char variable using C++.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    char val = 0xfe;

    std::stringstream ss1;
    std::stringstream ss2;

    ss1 << "#645" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex <<  val;
    ss2 << "#645" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << (int) val;

    std::cout << ss1.str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << ss2.str() << std::endl;
}
```

And my output:

```
#6450�
#645fffffffe
```

And what I expected:

```
#645FE
```

Comment: There are some solutions to the same question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673240/how-do-i-print-an-unsigned-char-as-hex-in-c-using-ostream

Comment: It´s where I got the first code from, but it works for `unsigned char` as pointed by sergej, not for `char`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick fix:

```
unsigned char val = 0xfe;
...
ss2 << "#645" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << std::uppercase << 
        (int) val;
```

or (as proposed by @Kerrek SB):

```
ss2 << "#645" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << std::uppercase <<
        static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(val));
```

Note that if (on your platform) `char` defaults to `signed char`, then
`0xfe` is a negative number (-2).

In other words, if `char` is a `signed char` and `sizeof(int)` is 4, then
`(int)val` is `0xfffffffe`. That is what you get.

- -2 as `signed char`: `0xfe`
- -2 as `int`: `0xfffffffe`

Comment: @Mendez: `static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(val))`

Comment: Kerrek, casting solved the issue without changing the type to `unsigned`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with streams manipulators when it's easier to do it yourself (exploiting the implicit conversion to unsigned char).

```
std::string hexb(unsigned char b) {
    const char *s="0123456789ABCDEF";
    return std::string(s[b>>4]) + s[b&0xf];
}
```

Usage:

```
std::cout<<hexb(val);
```