# If I use C-Style casts in my C++ project, is it worth refactoring to C++ casts?

Tags: c++, refactoring, casting

I use C-style casts in my 15K LOC C++ project, 90% of the times for casts between child and base classes.

Even when I read that it is bad to use them, and that they can result in severe errors, as they are not type safe as the C++ casts, I still *feel* perfectly fine and comfortable with using them.

I have not experienced a single bug in my project so far that was caused by, for example, an accidentally mistyped C-Style cast - really.

There are two main reasons I have not been using them:

- I didn't know enough about them yet
- I didn't like their syntax, they are more verbose and harder to read for me

My questions:

- (Why) Should I refactor my project to use C++-style casts?
- Why should I use C++-style casts for my future projects?

I use as good as all other advantages C++ offers me, from OOP including virtual and abstract base classes, namespaces, the STL, and so on, just not the new type casting syntax.  The argument "*Why aren't you just using C then?*" doesn't work for me.

Comment: Note that the C++-style casts are intentionally verbose; they stand out more!  And hopefully discourage you from using them except where strictly necessary.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. One should not wonder, "Which cast should I use?" One should wonder, "Why am I using casts?" If you don't use any casts at all, then the choice of which to use is moot. Is there something about your design that encourages you to use casts? Can you modify your design to avoid them?

Comment: Funny, I think C++ casts look _better_ than C  ones. But even if it were possibly to objectively say C++ ones look worse, that **still** wouldn't be a valid reason to avoid them. And again, if anything, I'd say they're _easier_ to understand than C casts, because C++ casts have defined powers, rather than just _try all these underlying types of cast until **something** 'works'_. So I can't agree with either of your reasons. Ah, well. Opinions.

Answer (score 90):

The main advantage of the C++-style casts is, as you've mentioned, the type safety.  Each cast in C++ handles one specific sort of conversion (or a family of related conversions) and so the compiler can go and check that you're not accidentally doing more conversions that you intended, or a sequence of conversions that fundamentally isn't safe.

One thing to think about is that while it's great that you feel comfortable using C-style casts, and while it's great that you haven't made any mistakes with them, other people working on the code base might not be as facile with these casts as you are.  Using the casting operators makes the code more self-documenting.  If you have a C-style cast somewhere, someone else reading the code might not be able to immediately infer what it is that you're doing.  If they see something like

```
T* ptr = (T*) var;
```

They might not immediately be able to tell if this is

1. A cast from a base class to a derived class or the other way around.
2. A cast to strip `const`ness off of `var`
3. A cast from an integral type to a pointer.

While they can probably glean this from context, it's a lot more obvious what's going on if you use a cast like

```
T* ptr = static_cast<T*>(var);
```

or

```
T* ptr = const_cast<T*>(var);
```

Another reason to prefer the C++-style casting operators is that they make the code more resilient to change.  For example, suppose I have this function:

```
void DoSomething(Base* ptr) {
    Derived* derived = (Derived *) ptr;
    DoSomethingElse(derived);
}
```

Now, suppose that I realize that this function isn't supposed to make any changes to its argument, so I decide to mark it `const`.  For example:

```
void DoSomething(const Base* ptr) {
    Derived* derived = (Derived *) ptr;
    DoSomethingElse(derived);
}
```

But now we have a problem - my C-style cast which used to just do a downcast now also strips off `const`ness.  This can lead to an easy bug where `DoSomethingElse` mutates the pointer I pass in, even though the `DoSomething` method itself promises not to do this.  If instead I wrote this code as

```
void DoSomething(Base* ptr) {
    Derived* derived = static_cast<Derived *>(ptr);
    DoSomethingElse(derived);
}
```

And then change the code by adding `const`:

```
void DoSomething(const Base* ptr) {
    Derived* derived = static_cast<Derived *>(ptr);
    DoSomethingElse(derived);
}
```

Now I'll get a compiler error telling me that my old cast is broken, which can lead me to discover that there is a logical error in the code (namely, that `DoSomethingElse` mutates its argument, so I can't naively make `ptr` a pointer-to-`const`.

So in short, using the C++ casting operators makes the code more readable and more maintainable.  It makes the logic behind the code more explicit.  And it makes the code less bug-prone by having the compiler catch errors either as you're making them or later on as you go back and change old code.  I would recommend trying to use C++-style casting operators in the future for these main reasons.

As for whether you should go back and try to replace your current C-style casts with C++-style casts, that's really up to you.  As an exercise, I'd suggest doing it just to practice learning what sorts of casts you're using.  Plus, you might find a logic error in there, which would make the search worth your while!

Comment: Really great explanation and examples

Comment: This answer is more verbose than C++ style casts!
...just playing; very informative :)

Answer (score 34):

In a company I used to work for, we once had to port a several million lines of code app to an new platform. What started out as "just another port to just another Unix platform" (the code already run on Windows, OSX, and half a dozen Unix-like platforms), turned out a huge problem. IIRC, the reason was that this platform had rather ***strict alignment requirements***, and some of our casts were tripping ***hardware exceptions*** due to misalignment.

This would have been easy enough to fix, if it weren't for the fact that a certain percentage of these casts were ***C-style casts***. It was impossible to ***effectively grep*** for these. Searches turned up literally ***tens of thousands of lines of code***, which all had to be ***inspected manually by human beings***, 99.99% of which were totally irrelevant.
It didn't help that us ***humans tended to miss*** a few of these hard-to spot casts, which would then have to be found in ***another round of reviewing*** tens of thousands of lines of code, 99.99%  of them exactly the same as in the first round.

That task was nigh impossible to finish in the time given, and ***almost broke the company's back***, because they were facing a severe contract penalty if we slipped the deadline.

Needless to say that afterwards it was decided to replace all C-style casts by their C++ counterpart. However, had this policy existed before we had to make that port...

Comment: I would certainly be interested why this was downvoted. Anything wrong with it?

Comment: Could you not just have run the code through GCC with `-Wold-style-cast`?  (Note, I didn't downvote!)

Comment: @Oli: I dunno, I was one of the Windows guys. `:)` I think they needed a platform-specific compiler with that. But yeah, if that warning already existed back then, we could have tried that. Do you have any idea whether this was already part of GCC about ten years ago? If so, I'll send those guys a mail, which will certainly stir them up. I'm pretty sure the story of this port is still a vital part of that company's folklore... `:)`

Comment: @sbi: I have no idea when that was introduced!

Comment: @sbi: Actually, a bit of digging has shown that it goes back at least as far as GCC 2.95.3, which was available in 2001!

Comment: @Oli: Ha! There's nothing about that being new on http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-2.95/features.html. OTOH, http://gcc.gnu.org/egcs-1.1/c++features.html and http://gcc.gnu.org/egcs-1.0/c++features.html don't list it either, and I doubt it goes back even further. Now if I only would find a certain date this was added to the compiler...

Comment: @kizzx2: To be frank, I don't even know which platform that was anymore, let alone if the underlying hardware was Intel.

Answer (score 10):

*(Why) Should I refactor my project to use C++-style casts?*

Yes.  For the same reason you should use them in the future.

*Why should I use C++-style casts for my future projects?*

The list is actually fairly long but I'll go over the most important.

First, they clearly state the intent of the cast.  Reading "static_cast" you know that the author intended to perform a static cast, rather than a reinterpret or const.

Second, they do one, and only one thing.  You can't accidentally cast away constness for example.

They're easy to search for.  Search for "const_cast" to find all casts to/from const.  How would you do this with C-style?  You couldn't.

They don't change cast kind when local code semantics change.  For example, `(Widget*)(blah)` will silently change to a reinterpret cast if Widget stops inheriting from whatever type blah was a pointer to.  It also changes to a reinterpret cast if the Widget definition is not locally available.  If you use new-style casts instead you'll get compiler vomit rather than a silent reinterpretation of the statement.

You can do a dynamic cast.  C-style casts can't do this.

Answer (score 9):

Well two parts:

> (Why) Should I refactor my project to use C++-style casts?

If your code works. Then don't fix it. Leave it as it is. Finding the C casts can be quite hard anyway. If you are working on the code and come across a C cast then change it as required.

> Why should I use C++-style casts for my future projects?

Because C casts are easy to get wrong.

Comment: ...until, as sbi has shown, it suddenly very much _doesn't_ work. A good argument for measured future-proofing, I'd say.

Answer (score 4):

If 90% of your casts are from sub-class to base-class, then removing them would be a start - they shouldn't be needed. If you have lots of casts from base to sub, then you are doing something else wrong.

The rest, you're telling the compiler that something strange is going on and you're breaking the rules - either the rules of the type system with a reinterpret_cast or a const_cast, you're risking representation with a static_cast to a smaller integral type, or you're breaking LSP and having to know about specific type of a sub-class when given a base-class.

Making those cases explicit is a good thing.

Comment: You're not always breaking the rules.  For instance, you may be promoting integer types in order to do maths correctly (e.g. `uint16_t a; uint16_t b; uint32_t c = (uint32_t)a * (uint32_t)b;`).

Comment: @Oli I tend to use the constructor syntax rather than casts for promotions, `uint16_t a; uint16_t b; uint32_t c = uint32_t(a) * uint32_t(b);`, since it fails for (most) narrowing conversions.

Comment: " Can you give an example where the constructor syntax does something different from the C-style cast?

Answer (score 3):

```
(Why) Should I refactor my project to use C++-style casts?
Why should I use C++-style casts for my future projects?
```

There's some good answers (including my own IMO) to the second question on [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527999/is-it-ok-to-use-c-style-cast-for-built-in-types/529022#529022)

For the first question, if I were in your position, I would substitute the C++ style casts for the C-style casts whenever I was already editing a file.  It's probably not worth setting aside a day or so to edit all your code and re-compile it, but it is probably worthwhile to incrementally improve your code-base when you're already working on it.

If you have time set aside for re-factoring activities, this would be a good candidate for that.

Comment: This was the answer I was going to give myself.  Do replace casts when you see them, but don't go hunting for them.

Answer (score 2):

Were I you, I would continue using C-style casts.  You have good reasons: you are not experiencing the alleged deficiencies of C-style casts, the C++ casts are more verbose, the C++ casts are harder to read and less familiar to you.

More generally, as a C++ programmer you will often read or be told that some way of doing things is the Old, Wrong, C way of doing things and that you should use the New, Correct, C++ way of doing things.  Some examples:

- you should use C++ style casts instead of C style casts
- you should use references instead of pointers
- you should use the "const" keyword a lot
- you should use generics instead of void pointers or typecasts
- you should use initializer lists instead of initializing member variables in the body of constructors
- you should use constructors instead of a post-construction initialization function
- you should never use macros

You will be usually be told that the new way is safer, that it lets the compiler catch more errors, and that it makes the code clearer.

I suggest you view such advice with suspicion.  Instead, consider: does using the new C++ feature solve a problem that you actually have?  Does it create new problems (by the way, increased code verbosity and decreased readability are problems)?  If the answer to the first question is no, or the answer to the first question is yes, you should consider sticking with the Old, Wrong, C way.

A side comment on code clarity: verbosity reduces clarity if the added text does not help a reader understand the program.  Were I you, I would view the claim that the C++ style casts improve code clarity skeptically, since you, a reader of your program, do not perceive a benefit.

I used to be the kind of person that always tried to use the New, Correct, C++ way.  I am no longer so dogmatic.  The essay at the below link was a big factor in changing my mind.

http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/

Comment: nitpick: generics are not templates

Comment: The majority of the things in your list really are *very good* advice, except in a handful of special cases.  You should be doing all of those by default, and only revert to "old-style" when you *need* to for whatever reason.  Otherwise, you're just intentionally making your code more error-prone.

Comment: I think you should add to the list: you should either be programming in C, or a much higher-level language than C++ (which seems to be the main point of that site).

Comment: The FQA is about 10% really good, 20% some basis in fact but presented really badly, and 70% FUD.  Of your seven points, I'd say #3, #4, #5, and #6 are universally true (#3 implies #5 and #6), #1 and #7 are circumstantially true, and #2 is a bunch of baloney.  Replace #2 with "You should use iterators or smart pointers instead of pointers, const references when copying is expensive, and non-const references only when overloading operators."  (Smart pointers replace pointers that own their target, iterators replace those that don't.)

Comment: Agree with @Ben.  Classic strawmen such as complaining that overloading arithmetic overloads can be confusing if you dynamically create the return value with `new` (http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/operator.html#fqa-13.1) mean that the majority of the FQA should be treated with extreme caution.

Comment: The point is not whether those suggestions are advisable or inadvisable.  Indeed, programming successfully in C++ requires extremely careful selection of programming techniques, since long compile times, indecipherable error messages, and very damaging failure modes like buffer overflows mean errors are punished severely.  The point is that suggestions about C++ techniques should be subject to critical analysis and that their utility should be analyzed in relation to the experience and problems of individual programmers and teams.