# Should I really use static_cast every single time I want to convert between primitive types?

Tags: c++, coding-style, casting, primitive

What makes this

```
long l = 1;
char c = static_cast<char>(l);

float f = 1.0f;
int i = static_cast<int>(f);
```

better than this

```
long l = 1;
char c = (char)l;

float f = 1.0f;
int i = (int)f;
```

when casting one primitive data type to another?

I've got much of legacy code that uses the second style for type casting in similar situations, so this is also a question about should I or may I not perform full-scale revision of that code.

Comment: You might find [Bjarne Stroustrup's answer](http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#static-cast) a good read.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Future-proofing.

Let's say in the future I do this:

```
float blah = 1.0f;
float* f = &blah;
```

Now, `int i = static_cast<int>(f);` stops compiling, but `int i = (int)f;` does a `reinterpret_cast`.

`static_cast<int>` is *this is exactly what I want you to do*. `(int)` is *do whatever you can to get me an int*. With the latter, the compiler will go out of its way to get you an `int` value, and that's rarely (never?) desirable.

Comment: Not really desirable, but it does happen. For example, one of the possible returns from [this function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585(v=vs.85).aspx) is a function pointer. The return type of the function is either `long` or `__int64`.

Comment: @chris Oh, that's weird. But a `reinterpret_cast` would work fine anyway.

Comment: Indeed. Most of the api is straight from C, and they use all kinds of "hacks" to do what they need to.

Answer (score 9):

The *every single time* is a bit of an indication.

You shouldn't be converting between primitive types so often that typing a few extra characters each time is an overly onerous task.  It's kind of like complaining that you have to wear a helmet every time you do some dangerous activity.  If you're finding wearing the helmet too annoying, the problem is likely that you're engaging in dangerous activity too often rather than the helmet requirement.

As for addressing legacy code, you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046755/i-use-c-style-casts-in-my-c-project-is-it-worth-refactoring-to-c-casts/5047038#5047038) for some answers (including my own).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you should.

Casts are a major source of bugs.  They are ways around the type-system, which is one of the best bug catchers available to programmers.

A static_cast is much more visible and *much more specific* than an old c-style cast.  You want them to stand out.  You want them to be obvious when you're debugging.  You want the next programmer to come along to understand why you're doing it.

The fact that it's harder to type `static_cast<blah>(foo)` is also a benefit, as it'll encourage you to cast only when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 3):

A constructor cast is an alternative. Assuming there is a conversion constructor defined. For example:

```
int i(0);
float f(3.14F);
i = int(f);
```

However you should definitely prefer `static_cast` and other C++ casts over a C-style cast as those basically say "try every cast until something works" which will eventually hit the equivalent of a `reinterpret_cast` and probably give you incorrect behavior.

Comment: AFAIK 'constructor cast' is equivalent to c-style cast.

Comment: It is perhaps *slightly* more type safe but yes you would get the same problem when introducing pointers. The ideal solution of course is not to cast at all and simply use the correct types.

Comment: When I say equivalent, I mean it. 5.2.3 pt 1: A simple type-specifier (7.1.6.2) or typename-specifier (14.6) followed by a parenthesized expression-list constructs a value of the specified type given the expression list. If the expression list is a single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding
cast expression (5.4).

Answer (score 1):

The issue with C-style casts is that it -may let you do conversions you didn't intend.

It is something you should do in the future but I wouldn't go back and change it unless you do find an issue.