# How to use static_cast in this statement

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

I have the statement:
`amount *= factor;`

`amount` is defined as an integer, where as `factor` is defined as double. So the result of multipling `amount` and `factor` would be of type `double`. I would like to use `static_cast` to make sure the resulting `amount` variable is converted to an `int`.

How would I do it in this case?

Comment: Why do you want to use `static_cast`? The result of multipling will be implicitly casted to `int` and assigned to `amount`.

Comment: This is part of a hw assignment stated as "Since the variable amount is an integer and the factor is a double, the product will be a double - to assighn back to an int for the updated amount value, just type cast to an int"  Should I not use static_cast?

Comment: No need to use `static_cast` explicitly here, the type cast will be done implicitly. And for `amount *= factor;` `static_cast` couldn't be used.

Comment: Oh really you're saying it would automatically be converted to int?

Comment: @David: You used the `*=` operator. This is an *assignment* operation; it says to multiply then assign the value. The result of an assignment operation is the value being assigned to.

Comment: You should probably read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654185/should-i-really-use-static-cast-every-single-time-i-want-to-convert-between-prim.

Comment: @David Yes, `amount` is declared as an `int`, it has to be casted to `int` before the assignment. If the cast couldn't be accomplished, compiler will complains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need cast here, it'll be automatically converted !!!