# Use enum classes with Boost Test

Tags: c++, boost-test, enum-class

I have an enum class that I would like to use in my unit tests:

```
enum class MyEnumClass
{
    MyEntryA,
    MyEntryB
};
```

I would like to use it as follows:

```
MyEnumClass myEnumValue = MyEnumClass::MyEntryA;
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(myEnumValue, MyEnumClass::MyEntryB);
```

But I get this error, clearly because boost test is trying to output the value:

```
include/boost/test/test_tools.hpp:326:14: error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
         ostr << t; // by default print the value
              ^
```

Adding ugly `static_cast` "solves" the problem:

```
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(static_cast<int>(myEnumValue), static_cast<int>(MyEnumClass::MyEntryB));
```

But I would like to avoid doing that for every enum class. I would also like to avoid defining `<<` stream operators for every enum class.

Is there a simpler way to use enum classes with boost test?

Or do other unit test frameworks have a better way to deal with enum classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I output the value of an enum class in C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421432/how-can-i-output-the-value-of-an-enum-class-in-c11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable printing of the type in question with `BOOST_TEST_DONT_PRINT_LOG_VALUE()`.  From the [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/test_output/testing_tool_output_disable.html):

```
typedef std::pair<int,float> pair_type;

BOOST_TEST_DONT_PRINT_LOG_VALUE( pair_type )
```

In this case should you get a mismatch, the test error message will tell you, but it but won't print the actual differing values.

Comment: Also, note that `BOOST_TEST_DONT_PRINT_LOG_VALUE()` can't be embedded in a namespace (at least in Boost 1.63.0).
`BOOST_TEST_DONT_PRINT_LOG_VALUE(MyEnumClass)  mynamespace { ... }` will work, but
`mynamespace {  BOOST_TEST_DONT_PRINT_LOG_VALUE(MyEnumClass) ... }` will not.

Comment: @dbank: Is that because the type in question is not part of the namespace?  What if you do something like `BOOST_TEST_DONT_PRINT_LOG_VALUE(::MyEnumClass)`?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but when I put `BOOST_TEST_DONT_PRINT_LOG_VALUE(MyEnumClass)` in a namespace, g++ would give macro expansion errors on `BOOST_TEST_DONT_PRINT_LOG_VALUE` and would cause any boost macros lower in the file to give errors, such as `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE` and `BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE`.

Comment: Also, in my case, the enum class declaration/definition was in a namespace.

Comment: Ah I see, doing `mynamespace { BOOST... }` tries to construct a type `mynamespace::boost::test_tools::...` which is where the problem comes from.  Not sure if this would be considered a bug or not - you could try asking on the Boost mailing list.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to use `BOOST_CHECK(myEnumValue == MyEnumClass::MyEntryB)`, instead of BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL.  This works for me, I'm assuming that for a simple true/false check, boost doesn't need to print out the enum class.

Comment: This is the least intrusive option. It is also your only option (well, together with Malveniouses) if you can't / don't want to provide a << operator for the class.

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

```
enum class MyEnumClass {
  MyEntryA,
  MyEntryB
};

MyEnumClass myEnumValue = MyEnumClass::MyEntryA;
BOOST_TEST((myEnumValue == MyEnumClass::MyEntryA)); // Note extra pair of brackets
BOOST_TEST((myEnumValue == MyEnumClass::MyEntryB)); // Note extra pair of brackets
```

Results:

```
info: check (myEnumValue == MyEnumClass::MyEntryA) has passed
error: in "Suite/Test": check (myEnumValue == MyEnumClass::MyEntryB) has failed
```

Details:

1. Use BOOST_TEST() as a test universal macro ([Assertion Boost Test Universal Macro](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/testing_tool_ref/assertion_boost_test_universal_macro.html)):

   - BOOST_TEST // or BOOST_TEST_CHECK
   - BOOST_TEST_REQUIRE
   - BOOST_TEST_WARN
2. It seems that scoped enums (enum classes) should be added to [Limitations and workaround](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/testing_tools/boost_test_universal_macro.html#boost_test_statement_limitations) that needs an extra pair of brackets.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Boost.Test has to print the value in case they are not equal, and it uses `operator<<` on a stream to do that.

In this case there's no cleaner way than to simply define `operator<<` on an `std::ostream` or to `static_cast` to an `int`, that I can see.

On the other hand, libraries like [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) do not have that requirements, and they probably use some macro magic to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution (so simple)

Add this at the top of your test file

```
#define CHECK_ENUM_CLASS_EQUAL(L, R) BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(static_cast<int>(L), static_cast<int>(R))
```

Example:

```
CHECK_ENUM_CLASS_EQUAL(a, MyEnumClass::MyEntryA);
```