# c++ Print an enum value

Tags: c++, enums

I have the following code (it's actually longer, i'm just putting up the part that throws an error)

```
//Header class
enum class Color{
    Rouge,  Bleu, Vert

};  

class Bike{
     Color _color;
     Bike (Color color): _color(color){
}

void print() const;
}

//Cpp file (assume all inclusions are done properly)
void Bike::print() const{
 std::cout<<_color;
}
//Main
main(){
    Color couleur (Color::Rouge);
    Bike obj(couleur);
    obj.print()


}
```

So everything else works perfectly until i print the color (`std::cout<<_color;`). I'm i using `enum` in the wrong way? why can't i print that color?

error code

```
[Error] initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = Color]'
```

Comment: It's already explained by someone here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11421471/5420624

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from making your constructor and `print` function `public`, you should also know that `enum class` is not implicitly convertible to `int`. So you could either manually convert it to `int` in the `print` function:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(_color);
```

or overload the output operator for the `Color`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, Color c)
{
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(c);
    return o;
}
```

This way, you could do some better output for your color - perhaps output a string representation of your enum values.

Here's a live example on [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/9x76)

Comment: Thank you, so if i want to output the actual string, i will have to do a bunch of `if-then else` statement? seems very inefficient

Comment: @ApexPredator I'd search around if I were you for how to do this without kind of duplicating stuff. The simplest solution though is to use an array of names in the output operator: `static std::array<const char*, 3> enumNames = {"Red", "Blue", "Green"}; std::cout << enumNames[static_cast<int>(c)];`