# error: no match for ‘operator<<’ defining by ostream in c++

Tags: c++

I want to overload `<< operator`. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

enum class Zustand{Neuwertig,Gut,Abgegriffen,Unbrauchbar};

class Exemplar{
private:
    int aufl_num;
    Zustand z;
    bool verliehen;

public:
    Exemplar(int aufl_num);
    Exemplar(int aufl_num,Zustand z);
    bool verfuegbar() const;
    bool entleihen();
    void retournieren(Zustand zust);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Exemplar& Ex);
};

//Constructor 1;
Exemplar::Exemplar(int aufl_num):
    aufl_num{aufl_num},
    z{Zustand::Neuwertig},
    verliehen{false}
    {
        if(aufl_num >1000 || aufl_num <1) throw runtime_error("Enter correct number betwee 1 and 1000");

    }

// Constructor 2;
Exemplar::Exemplar(int aufl_num,Zustand z):
    aufl_num{aufl_num},
    z{z},
    verliehen{false}
    {
        if(aufl_num >1000 || aufl_num <1) throw runtime_error("Enter correct number betwee 1 and 1000");

    }


ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Exemplar& Ex){
    if(Ex.verliehen == true){
        os << "Auflage:" << Ex.aufl_num <<","<< "Zustand:"<<Ex.z<<","<<"verliehen";
    }else{
        os << "Auflage:" << Ex.aufl_num <<","<< "Zustand:"<<Ex.z;
    }

}
```

I declared my `ostream& operator<<` as a friend function, definitions inside class and function code seemse to be the same. But I have no idea, why compiler throws me an error "error: no match for ‘operator<<’. Can you help me to figure out where is the problem?

Error message:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Exemplar&)’:
main.cpp:72:53: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘const Zustand’)
   os << "Auflage:" << Ex.aufl_num <<","<< "Zustand:"<<Ex.z<<","<<"verliehen";
```

Comment: Please include the full error message, it will say what types the compiler was trying to call `operator<<` with.

Comment: [mcve], please. The code you show doesn't even attempt to call that `operator<<`. Beyond that, try to remove unrelated details (but keep the code compilable with *just that error you ask about*).

Comment: I guess the compiler is complaining about the missing `operator <<` for type `Zustand`.

Comment: Look closely at your error message. The problem is not with the `<<` overload for your `Exemplar` class, but the fact that no `<<` overload is defined for your enumeration class.

Comment: Doesn't you error complain about outputting `Ex.z`, which is an `enum class`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421432/how-can-i-output-the-value-of-an-enum-class-in-c11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is quite simple. You try to call: `os << Ex.z`, where `z` is a `Zustand`, and that `Zustand` has no `ostream` operator implemented for it. You may want to print out the value of that `enum` as an integer. The compiler doesn't know how to print out a `Zustand`, so you have to tell it how to.

Comment: But in order to print a word(instead of integer), should I overload << operator for enum class as well?

Comment: Yes, you have to do that. However, you will have to get a corresponding string for each enum value, since there is no way to cast it.

Comment: @Rob_Fir Yes. The *names* "Neuwertig, Gut, Abgegriffen, Unbrauchbar" do not appear *as strings* in your program, you have to have some strings with those values *somewhere* if you want them

Comment: @Rob_Fir If you have multiple enums where you want to associate the text of the name with each value, [have a look here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/14315/82515) for an implementation

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
os << "Auflage:" << Ex.aufl_num <<","<< "Zustand:"<<Ex.z<<","<<"verliehen";
```

into

```
os << "Auflage:" << Ex.aufl_num <<","<< "Zustand:"
   << static_cast<std::underlying_type<Zustand>::type>(Ex.z) 
   <<","<<"verliehen";
```

and similarly the second line.