# Writing "enum: int64_t" value to std::ostringstream truncates it to int

Tags: c++, enums, overloading, c++17

This code behaves in an unexpected way with MSVC compiler (v141 toolset, /std:c++17):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    enum Enum : int64_t {muchos_digitos = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max() - 1000};
    ss << muchos_digitos;
    std::cout << ss.str();
    return 0;
}
```

Specifically, it prints "-1001". It is only after much head scratching and enabling `/W4` warning level that I discovered the cause:

> warning C4305: 'argument': truncation from 'main::Enum' to 'int'

But why does it happen? Indeed, the debugger confirms that `int` overload is called instead of `long long`, but why? And how can I circumvent this in generic code? I could cast `muchos_digitos` to `int64_t`, but I receive the value as `typename T`. I can figure out that it's an enum, but how can I know that it's a strongly typed enum, and can I find out its underlying type? I don't think it's directly possible...

The output is correct under GCC, but I need the code to work with all three of GCC, clang and MSVC.

**[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/C4RMnk)**

P. S. It was a mistake that /W4 was not set for my project in the first place. I recommend everyone to use this level with MSVC and `-pedantic-errors` with GCC / clang, it really saves you time with bizzare errors and surprising behavior when you notice it at compile time as you write the code.

Comment: What is really bizarre is that if I hover over the << intelisense tells me it has picked the long long overload.  Must be a bug but I'm not finding anything reported on it.

Comment: Not an answer as to _why_, but you can solve this issue in a way that works with templates using methods from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421432/how-can-i-output-the-value-of-an-enum-class-in-c11

Comment: @rtpax: thanks, didn't know about `std::underlying_type`!

Comment: When using C++, it is best to use standard C++ header files, including the "C++ wrapped C" header files, and avoid standard C header files.  So rather than `<stdint.h>` instead use `<cstdint>`.

Comment: @Eljay: thanks. I've heard that recommendation many times, but in my 8+ years of programming I never understood the rationale. To be honest, these "wrapped" headers look suspicious to me.

Comment: The rationale being that the C++ wrapped C header files put the symbols in the `std` namespace, remove some C macros and use C++ inline functions instead, and provide properly overloaded C++ version instead of the non-overloaded C version.

Comment: @Eljay: I have never noticed the benefits. Whenever I needed an overload, the "old" header also had it. And the plain .h headers are almost always included anyway by some third-party libraries, or maybe even by the platform headers, at least on Windows. Just my personal experience with a bunch of projects. I'm not saying you're wrong; I know you're right. But to me, including "new" headers seems redundant, just more stuff for the compiler to parse and more symbols to pollute the namespace.

Comment: @Eljay: C++ projects usually end up indirectly including the good old C header files anyway, so it really doesn't matter.  In fact, most C++ code in the wild is written expecting good old C functions like `strlen()` to be in global scope, which is only guaranteed to be portable if you include the good old C header files.

Comment: File a bug with MSVC. This should promote to the underlying type.

Comment: You want to prefer `<stdint.h>` in the same way you don't want to use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: You got MS feedback in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/475488/wrong-ostringstreamoperator-overload-selected-for.html
 that this is a bug and it is fixed in VS2019. Can you please post this as an answer here and accept it!? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was confirmed to be a bug by the Microsoft team and it's now fixed in VS 2019: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/475488/wrong-ostringstreamoperator-overload-selected-for.html