# Convert unsigned char[10] to QBytearray;

Tags: c++, qt, converters, unsigned-char, qbytearray

I've seen a lot o questions around this, but so far none worked for me.

I've tried the 2 most common answers but I get the same error.

being but an `unsigned char buf[10];`

this,

```
QByteArray databuf;
databuf = QByteArray::fromRawData(buf, 10);
```

or this,

```
QByteArray databuf;
databuf = QByteArray(buf, 10);
```

got me the same error,

`error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned char*' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]`

any advice?

thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's just signedness issue, so this should work:

```
databuf = QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), 10);
```

Or with legacy C-style cast:

```
databuf = QByteArray((char*)buf, 10);
```

([Here's one of many many discussions about which you should use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527999/is-it-ok-to-use-c-style-cast-for-built-in-types))

Easier alternative is to remove `unsigned` from declaration of `buf`, if you don't need it there for some other reason.

Note, that if you use that `fromRawData` method, it does not copy the bytes, so better be sure `buf` won't go out of scope too soon. If unsure, do not use it...

Comment: well I need it. I get `error: invalid static_cast from type 'unsigned char [10]' to type 'char*'`

Comment: My unedited answer used `static_cast`, here's linked question for why it does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151834/why-cant-i-static-cast-between-char-and-unsigned-char

Answer (score 1):

As it says, the argument passed to `fromRawData` should be a `const char*`, not an `unsigned char*`. You could make your array be an array of `const char`:

```
const char buf[10];
```

The array can be converted to a pointer to its first element which will a `const char*`, exacly as `fromRawData` expects.

Comment: should I create a new `char *array` and pass the data from `buf` first to the array and then convert it?