# Homemade toupper: looks the same but not identical

Tags: c++, r, string, rcpp, toupper

For my optimizations, i would like to get a decent `toupper` in Rcpp. I'm very new to C++, and as for know I've done that:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

void C_toupper_String(const String& s) {
  for (char *p =(char *)s.get_cstring();*p!=0;p++) *p = toupper(*p);
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
StringVector C_toupper(StringVector const& vecteur) {
  StringVector res=clone(vecteur);
  for (int i(0); i < res.size(); ++i) {
    C_toupper_String(res[i]);
  }
  return res;
}

/*** R
teststring <- "HeY I arNaud"
C_toupper(teststring)
toupper(teststring)
identical(C_toupper(teststring),toupper(teststring))
*/
```

However, it doesn't work as it should.

```r
> C_toupper(teststring)
[1] "HEY I ARNAUD"

> toupper(teststring)
[1] "HEY I ARNAUD"

> identical(C_toupper(teststring),toupper(teststring))
[1] FALSE
```

What's the problem? If possible, I would like not to convert `String` into `std::string`, because I would like to understand what's happening: the point of going into C++ is to be able to avoid copies and conversions.

Thanks,

Arnaud

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to achieve since `Rcpp::clone()` will copy your data.

Comment: Ralf Stubner : I wanted to be able to do it when I want it and not to when I don't want to. I want to understand how the Rcpp::String works, and directly being able to modify it safely. Anyway, it doesn't even copy the data as i've noticed the test string is modified... That's a total fail lol

Comment: https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/170_string.html get_cstring is making a copy so you modify the copy, not the original

Comment: What makes you think that a reimplementation in Rcpp would be faster than R’s builtin `toupper` function?

Comment: @OlivierSohn That’s not correct, and the link doesn’t claim that either.

Comment: @KonradRudolph My point isn't to be "faster". However I need StringVector for cpp functions I write ; and I wanted to get better at manipulating those, without preparing everything in R or without turning to std::string (which makes copy and hence make it a slower). It seems like it is above my knowledge ; hence I'll prepare everything in R before

Comment: However I'm still curious. If someone can explain what's happening with the unpredictable FALSE identical I'd like to know

Comment: @KonradRudolph when I read this: 15.3.7 get_cstring()
Convert the string of this String object into a C character string constant (const char*) and return it, I tend to think that the c character string constant is a disctinct memory area than the "string of this String", so modifying the c character string constant will not modify the "string of this String"...

Comment: @OlivierSohn Conversion in C++ in general does not imply copying. In this case it just returns a pointer to the internal storage. That said, it's a `const` pointer so the whole code is UB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question why the two strings don’t test `identical` is difficult to explain — the two strings certainly look identical when inspecting their raw bytes (via `charToRaw`), they do not carry attributes, and they don’t have an encoding set. So, really, they should be identical.

To solve the mystery, we need to understand what your C++ code is actually doing. More specifically, what the C-style cast in `C_toupper_String` is doing. Because of their danger, [you should *never* use C-style casts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/528009/1968). Your code is running into problems purely because of that cast.

Why? Because [`String::get_cstring`](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/classRcpp_1_1String.html#a56a271a7a2aad835e26631a42adcb680) returns `char const*`. You are casting it to `char*` and thereby casting away its `const`ness. This *can* be safe, but only if the underlying storage isn’t `const`. Otherwise it’s [undefined behaviour (UB)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). The effects of UB are difficult to predict due to code rewriting (e.g. optimisations). In this case, it seems that it produces code that messes up the R string internals.

---

You fundamentally *cannot* modify `Rcpp::String` objects in place, they don’t allow it. But if you merely want to avoid copying then your code is failing its aim anyway, since your `C_toupper` function explicitly copies the input in the first step.

As Dirk said, the correct way of solving this problem is to use the available Rcpp API. And in the case of string modifications, this means converting your input to `std::string`, performing the modifications, and then converting back. This does copy, but so does your current code. Here’s one good way of writing this code:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::StringVector C_toupper(Rcpp::StringVector const& vec) {
    std::vector<std::string> res(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    for (std::string& str : res) {
        for (char& c : str) c = std::toupper(c);
    }

    return Rcpp::wrap(res);
}
```

Do note that this *will* sometimes produce wrong results, because `std::toupper` fundamentally can’t deal with certain Unicode characteristics. R’s `toupper` does better but also has some problems. A *proper* solution is using the [{stringr}](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/case.html) or {stringi} packages.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks for taking the time to do this.

Comment: Thanks for all that. I've understood that it's not safe to directly try to deal with the memory. I'll check my code to see I didn't break consts in other places. I guess the storage is more complex than a single char chain.

Comment: @ArnaudFeld It is more or less a char array + header that stores the string data.  It's not that the structure is too complex, it's that R uses a global string cache and modifying something directly in the cache breaks assumptions that R makes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a one-liner using the C++ library?  Unless you a *really* experienced in C++  you may be somewhat unlikely to beat it.  The following code is just indented for display here, it is one line in my R session here.

```
R> Rcpp::cppFunction("std::string tU(std::string s) { std::string u(s); \
 for (unsigned int i=0; i<u.length(); i++) u[i] = std::toupper(u[i]); return(u); }")
R> tU("aBcDe")
[1] "ABCDE"
R>
```

Comment: This doesn’t explain why OP’s code yields a string that looks identical but doesn’t test `identical` to the result of `toupper` (or your code). Even examining them with `charToRaw` doesn’t indicate any difference, their encodings are identical, and they don’t seem to have any attributes.

Comment: Thanks.for your answer. However, as I told, I'd prefer to avoid turning the std::string. As @KonradRudolph tells, the main point is to undestand what happens.

Comment: @Konrad:  Sure, but as has been stated before, if one's goal is to shoot oneself in the foot going directly to C level routines is a good choice ;-)  It is not my problem if OP cooks up some code that does not pass `identical`.  We have (literally) thousands on entry points to Rcpp code that pass.  His problem, not mine.  And surely a good learning opportunity for him.

Comment: Or phrased differently:  We aim to give higher-level access so that users do not have to worrry about bitwise idendity.  One generally just gets it for free: Rcpp-created objects are generally indistinguishable from R-created ones.  Here he managed to break that with homegrown code bypassing our structures.  Which would be ... his problem not mine, but as a said, likely a good learning and debugging opportunity.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I’m fully on your side when it comes to teaching the right way rather than giving literal answers to XY problems. However, you’re brushing aside a really rather interesting problem here: it’s absolutely not obvious why `identical` fails — in fact, even after looking at the source code of `R_compute_identical` I haven’t got a clue what could be going on here. The only thing I could see is that their `sxpinfo->obj` flag differs. Also, avoiding copies on the C++ side hardly sounds like a foolish idea. There are just better ways to do this than OP’s way.

Comment: Shrug. But that's why we have `identical` and `all.equal` in R. It can be tricky.  Plus characters have possible encodings issue are a _whole_ different and new mess that is also OS dependent so I have learned to stay away from it as best as I can.  Sometimes defensive programming is simply better.  At least in my eyes and hence the answer I posted which started this thread.

Comment: And you are getting to it in the second part of your comment.  `SEXP` is, to me, an opaque structure.  Some of the bitsets have no user accessible setters/getters. So if it differs ... I would simply code up a different approach.  Life's too short and all that (when one lives in application land; library writers still have to care and cope but we have not demonstrated an Rcpp bug here so I will now excuse myself from this fascinating but ultimately pointless discussion).

Comment: Hi,
I didn't mean to "break high-level access" nor trying to get a litteral XY answer. And I never told it was a Rcpp bug !

Comment: Hi, reading about informations i just realized i talked with the rcpp developer, which i didn't know. Thanks for your excellent package anyway.